# Why "cfgadm" does not show "med-changer" device of SAS attached tape-library?

Tags: tape, openindiana, illumos, omnios

Trying to set up a tape library **NEOs StorageLoader** LTO7 and also old **PowerVault 124T** I am facing following problem and cannot find any helpful answer.

Using either **Openindiana 151a8**, **Openindiana Hipster 2017.4** or current **SmartOS** none of them creates device for tape-changer LUN1 (to be used by **mtx**). Only tape-drive device (LUN0) is shown:

```
user@server1:~# cfgadm -al
Ap_Id                          Type         Receptacle   Occupant     Condition
...
c3::rmt/1                      tape         connected    configured   unknown
...
```

Which maps to /dev/rmt/1 and is perfectly usable by **mt** tool.
I have read a lot about using **devfsadm -C -v** and booting with reconfigure option but nothing solved situation.

How to get **/dev/scsi/changer/...** for **mtx** ?

BTW: Tape library is attached to LSI 9207-4i4e HBA controller and OS driver for this is **mpt_sas**, which seems to see LUN1 according to LSIUtil and boot screen output. /var/adm/messages does not show any useful info execpt a warning, that multipathing will be disabled due to invalid WWN of tape-changer.

Answer (score 2):

Very easy to solve (after hours of wasting time by trying to modify */kernel/drv/sgen.conf* and some others as suggested by driver's man pages):

Simply configure system to use **sgen** driver for SCSI tape-changer LUN by issuing following command:

```
user@server1:~# update_drv -av -i '"scsiclass,08"' sgen
exit status = 0
devfsadm[1384]: verbose: symlink /dev/scsi/changer/c3t500E09E0001BFE72d1 -> ../../../devices/pci@0,0/pci8086,e04@2/pci1000,3030@0/iport@8/medium-changer@w500e09e0001bfe72,1:changer
```

et voilà

```
user@server1:~# cfgadm -al
Ap_Id                          Type         Receptacle   Occupant     Condition
...
c3::rmt/1                      tape         connected    configured   unknown
c3::scsi/changer/c3t5000E1116  med-changer  connected    configured   unknown
...
```

Proof that device is handled by sgen driver:

```
user@server1:~# cat /etc/path_to_inst | grep sgen
"/pci@0,0/pci8086,e04@2/pci1000,3030@0/iport@8/medium-changer@w5000e11164a8d002,1" 1 "sgen"
```

Now **mtx** is ready to operate the robot:

```
user@server1:~# mtx -f /dev/scsi/changer/c3t5000E11164A8D002d1 inquiry
Product Type: Medium Changer
Vendor ID: 'BDT     '
Product ID: 'FlexStor II     '
Revision: '5.10'
Attached Changer API: No
```

If links in /dev tree are messed up you may use devfsadm to clean up:

```
user@server1:~# devfsadm -C -v
```

BTW: Tape drive needs probalby needs **st** SCSI driver which was used automatically during my execises. But you may also need

```
update_drv -av -i '"scsiclass,01"' st
```

See also *add_drv* and *rem_drv* commands.

Comment: See also this discussion: http://omnios-discuss.omniti.narkive.com/00ftEEPN/sas-tape-driver